# Python Request not allowing redirects

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I am using Python request library to **scrape** robots.txt data from a list of URLs:

```
for url in urls:
    url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, "robots.txt")
    try: 
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers,  allow_redirects=False) 
        r.raise_for_status()
        extract_robots(r)
    except (exceptions.RequestException, exceptions.HTTPError, exceptions.Timeout) as err:
        handle_exeption(err)
```

In my list of urls, I have this webpage: https://reward.ff.garena.com. When I am requesting https://reward.ff.garena.com/robots.txt, I am directly redirected to https://reward.ff.garena.com/en. However, I specified in my request parameters that I don't want redirects `allow_redirects=False`.

How can I skip this kind of redirect and make sure I only have `domain/robots.txt` data calling my `extract_robots(data)` method?

Comment: maby use HTTPSConnectionPool Exception in except part is usefull

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for sure that there is a robots.txt at that location?
I note that if I request https://reward.ff.garena.com/NOSUCHFILE.txt that I get the same result as for robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

The `allow_redirects=False` only stops `requests` from automatically following 302/location= responses - i.e. it doesn’t stop the server you’re trying to access from returning a redirect as the response to the request you’re making.

If you get this type of response I guess it indicates the file you requested isn’t available, or some other error preventing you accessing it, perhaps in the general case of file access this might indicate need for authentication but for robots.txt that shouldn’t be the problem - simplest to assume the robots.txt isn’t there.